# Mouse hovering on KML layer in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, kml

I am using ArcGIS API for JavaScript for map.

i want show an popup info window when mouse hover on kml layer.

I am trying this code for and using  mouse-over event , But this is not working on kml layer.

my code is:

```
 var kmlUrl = "http://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/a7c2aaaa083741f58825cc3f39c53a22/data";

          var kml = new KMLLayer(kmlUrl); 

            map.addLayer(kml);
            kml.on("load", function() {
              domStyle.set("loading", "display", "none");

            }); 

           kml.on("mouse-over",function (event) {
             alert('test');
          });
```

Comment: i think 'mouse-over' isn't working because that event is not defined for the class in the api reference https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/kmllayer-amd.html

Comment: Is there any other way to trigger an event when we mouse over on the kml layer feature?.How can i know that on which feature an mouse-over occur on the kml layer ?

Comment: unfortunately, i'm not sure.